# auto scroll on a page only working if ctrl+click the button using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i'm still new on jquery and  this is my code(i placed this inside html)

```
 $("button").click(function(){
     $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".test").offset().top},
        1000);
});
```

and this is inside my html :

```
<form method="GET">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<div class="test">Hello</div>
```

after i clicked the button , it doesn't scroll the page instead .
the page only scrolled if i ctrl+click the button 
did i miss something here ?
i'm currently using jquery ver 2.1.4

Comment: try this scrollTop: $(".test").position().top

Comment: i already a found a problem that it's not scrolled because i placed the button inside the <form> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use id in Button to be more specific

```
<button id='scroll'>Submit</button>
```

then

```
$('#scroll').click(function){
$('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop : 0                       
      }, 500);
});
```

Or i don't know if jquery 2.1.4 supports the new way

```
$(document).on('click','#scroll',function(){
  $('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop : 0                       
  }, 500);  
});
```

Hope this Helps

Comment: may i know what's the most version jquery did u use

Comment: jquery 3.2.1 @wumBo_

Answer (score 0):

you did not set height of your div and also your button should have type="button". please see this with jquery 2.1.4

http://plnkr.co/edit/mFCGoLZ4BCLRSpGTDzYk?p=preview

```
'http://plnkr.co/edit/mFCGoLZ4BCLRSpGTDzYk?p=preview'
```